# How to monitor tomcat logs with Elastic stack in ubuntu

Tags: devops, tomcat8, elastic-stack

I am configuring tomcat8 logs into Elastic stack dashboard using the following reference link:
https://logz.io/blog/apache-tomcat-monitoring/

I am using a ubuntu 18.04 server installed tomcat8 and configured the logstash.conf file and filebeat file but the logs are not displayed in the kibana dashboard

Can you please update how to configure this scenario?

```
Here is my filebeat.yml file

filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
enabled: true
paths:
- /var/log/tomcat8/localhost_access_log.2019-09-11.txt
- /var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out.1
- /var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out

#------------- Logstash output ------------------------
               output.logstash:
               # The Logstash hosts
               hosts: ["localhost:5044"]


enter code here
```

This is my .conf file

```
input {
beats {
port => 5044

}

filter {
grok {
  match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }

date {
  match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]

 geoip {
  source => "localhost"

 }

output {
 elasticsearch {
hosts => ["172.17.5.106:9200"]

}

curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v"
health status index                           uuid                   pri       rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-6-2019.09.11 gbOahp_KS56HZfeSVt0sgQ   1    0       8639            0        2mb            2mb
green  open   .monitoring-es-6-2019.09.08     NmS7exwcQA-OTgAxVWtQBA   1   0     103690           40     38.1mb         38.1mb
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-6-2019.09.08 JnOFYqNZRceaj5GA6WmL4Q   1   0       8639            0      1.9mb          1.9mb
green  open   .monitoring-es-6-2019.09.11     CXhPOf6xSDiG9bnGs58SEQ   1   0     155586           84     62.4mb         62.4mb
green  open   .monitoring-es-6-2019.09.12     RyhD98zwTVKPvl1BzDECug   1   0      64468          160     27.6mb         27.6mb
green  open   .monitoring-es-6-2019.09.09     VUIiK99ESdaGMoIOKzvstg   1   0     121067           80     47.1mb         47.1mb
green  open   .kibana_task_manager            KnCr7PerTyeFmwcwz0IamA   1   0          2            0     12.6kb         12.6kb
green  open   .kibana_1                       Lu5oH-BgSheJdAwKGXutqw   1   0        198           34      378kb          378kb
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-6-2019.09.07 te49nDoDQH2g12C3bOluvQ   1   0       8639            0      1.9mb          1.9mb
green  open   .monitoring-es-6-2019.09.10     ne6d71h1Ri2fJ2joOxV4Yw   1   0     138256           60     54.1mb         54.1mb
green  open   .monitoring-es-6-2019.09.07     I4Z0SlDjShabcVOl9oGJPQ   1   0      86414           42     31.6mb         31.6mb
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-6-2019.09.09 ruXbntBHTl6yrSkj0tormg   1   0       8640            0        2mb            2mb
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-6-2019.09.06 Go1pi-NhT8eVlKX2QgMMKA   1   0       3007            0    828.3kb        828.3kb
green  open   .monitoring-es-6-2019.09.06     oCgFiC1dRr-wjw0tdGxlRw   1   0      24058           28      9.8mb          9.8mb
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-6-2019.09.12 jr5nRZgtSAebP1jbCeQDxQ   1   0       3221            0    821.2kb        821.2kb
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-6-2019.09.10 seRLoCjXRtGU9U3ZiSl2Fw   1   0       8639            0        2mb            2mb
```

here is my /var/log/filebeat/filebeat file

2019-09-11T17:12:04.655+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:144  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":27$
2019-09-11T17:12:34.655+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:144  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":27$
2019-09-11T17:13:04.655+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:144  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":27$
2019-09-11T17:13:34.655+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:144  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":27$
2019-09-11T17:14:04.655+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:144  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":27$
2019-09-11T17:14:34.655+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:144  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":27$
2019-09-11T17:15:04.655+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:144  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":27$
2019-09-11T17:15:34.655+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:144  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":27$

this is my /var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log file

[2019-09-08T00:00:13,284][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.8.3"}
[2019-09-08T00:00:14,084][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::Config$
[2019-09-08T00:00:14,228][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2019-09-08T00:00:19,281][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
[2019-09-08T00:00:49,251][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.8.3"}

Comment: Please add the relevant log files (Filebeat and Logstash) and the output of `GET _cat/indices` from Elasticsearch (to see what's getting into Elasticsearch or not).

Comment: Ok, so the data doesn't make it into Elasticsearch. Please add the Filebeat and the Logstash log files (the configs are a good starting point but not enough). If this is Ubuntu, they should be in `/var/log/filebeat/filebeat` and `/var/log/logstash/...`

Comment: hello..is there any other approach to ship tomcat logs to kibana dashboard.?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm your full filebeat.yml configuration? Looks like you are missing the filebeat output section.

You can check the logz.io link you posted or the official documentation on the logstash output: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/logstash-output.html

```
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

Comment: i have added output.logstash could you just look into it. is there any alternate approach to ship tomcat logs to kibana dashboard ?.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "could you just look into it"? How are things after you added the output? Because the output wasn't configured, it means your logs were never being sent to logstash. Make sure you replace 'localhost' in output.logstash if your logstash instance is not on the same host as your filebeat instance. Can you check the indices again using the command that xeraa provided and see if there are any indices that don't begin with `.` as those are system indices? Anything in the logs for filebeat, logstash, elasticsearch, or kibana?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Filebeat log it's working fine.

But in your Logstash configuration, `input {`, `date {`, `geoip {`, and `output {` are missing a closing `}`.
And I'm not really sure about your `geoip` filter — that field is really called `localhost`? To keep it simple, I'd remove that part and get the rest working first.

Try the following config:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
  }

  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["172.17.5.106:9200"]
  }
}
```

If it doesn't work, please update your answer with the new log output of Logstash.